# Trouble checking if a string is a palindrome

Tags: java

I am a beginner learning Java and have been asked to check if a given string is a palindrome.

Here is what I have so far:

```
   int namel = name.length();
    for (int i =0; i<=namel; i++)
    {
      char letter = name.charAt(i);
      char namerev = name.charAt(namel-i);
      String letterS =txtNamePali.getText();
      if(letter==namerev)
      {
         txtNamePali.setText("Palindrone");
      }
      else
      {
          txtNamePali.setText( "Not a Palindrone");
      }
    }
```

Unfortunately my textbox isn't showing any output. I have searched for how to fix the issue but couldn't find an answer relating to what I have learnt in class.

What did I do wrong, and how can I correct it?

Comment: Might want to start by looking at your indexing.  Let's say you have a word 5 letters long, so namel == 5, your code is attempting to do this:  name.charAt(0) and name.charAt(5). I would imagine this would

Comment: Your code will throw an error...you need to change your loop to i < namel not <= namel

Comment: Indexes of characters start from `0` and end in `length()-1`.

Comment: That is quite a trap as an exercise for a beginner; I am not sure that the one giving the exercise is aware that a same Unicode code point may be represented by more than 1 `char`...

Answer (score 4):

I think the easiest test is to use the [`StringBuilder.reverse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse%28%29) to construct the reverse of the input. Also, the word is usually spelled *palindrome*.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(name);
sb.reverse();
String msg = (sb.toString().equals(name)) ? "Palindrome" : "Not a Palindrome";
txtNamePali.setText(msg);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)

Use the [reverse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#reverse()) function in that.
Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    String str = "1234";
    String str1 = "1234321";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append(str);
    if(stringBuilder.reverse().toString().equals(str)){
        System.out.println("Palindrome");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Palindrome");
    }
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    stringBuilder.append(str1);
    if(stringBuilder.reverse().toString().equals(str1)){
        System.out.println("Palindrome");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Not Palindrome");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Not Palindrome
Palindrome
```

Int short you can just do

```
new StringBuilder().append(yourString).reverse().toString().equals(yourString)
```

This return a boolean true if the string is palindrome else false.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is on the right track, but as some people have said, there are a few errors you need to account for, which should appear as compiler issues.

```
int namel = name.length();
boolean isPalindrome = true; 
//add a tracking value, it's a palindrome unless we prove it otherwise
for (int i =0; i< namel/2; i++) 
//change from <= to < because arrays are 0-index, we also only have to check halfway so we can use namel/2
{
    char letter = name.charAt(i);
    char namerev = name.charAt(namel-i);
    //String letterS =txtNamePali.getText(); <-- not sure what this was for, possibly a debug statement
    if(letter!=namerev)
    {
        isPalindrome = false; //we have found a non-matching value, it'll stay false, and we'll output correctly
    }
}

//then we set the text once. Keeping the text inside would have returned an erroneous "abbc" is a palindrome.

if(isPalindrome) {
    txtNamePali.setText("Palindrone");  
}
else {
    txtNamePali.setText( "Not a Palindrone");   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.The result of the method should be given when the whole string got checked. So first put

```
  if(letter==namerev)
  {
     txtNamePali.setText("Palindrone");
  }
  else
  {
      txtNamePali.setText( "Not a Palindrone");
  }
```

outside the loop (and change the condition - like in my proposal below). 
you can break the loop when the first mismatch of two chars occured.

2.Instead of `char namerev = name.charAt(namel-i);` you have reduce the position one more.
So use: `char namerev = name.charAt(namel-1-i);`

try something like this:

```
    String s = "stringtotest";
    boolean result = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(s.length()-1-i)) {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (result)
        System.out.println("Palindrom");
    else
        System.out.println("Not palindrom");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    String name="pop";   // string to check if it palindrome or not
    String revName="";
     int namel = name.length();

     for (int i =1; i<=namel; i++)
        {
          char namerev = name.charAt(namel-i);
         revName += namerev;
        }     

          if(name.equals(revName))
          {
             System.out.println("Palindrome");
          }
          else
          {
              System.out.println( "Not a Palindrome");
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Same general idea as the others, but I think that this is cleaner and easier to read. Just a thought - everyone has their own style. :) If you're a beginner, I highly suggest getting into the habit of moving redundant logic to its own method. It's cleaner and may prove to be  much more useful later.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main( String args[] ) {

        for ( String string : args ) {
            if ( isPalendrome( string ) {
                System.out.println("Palindrome");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Not a Palindrome");
            }
        }

    }

    private static boolean isPalindrome( String string ) {
        return string.equals( reverse( string ) );
    }

    private static String reverse( String original ) {
        return new StringBuilder(original).reverse().toString();
    }

}
```